# Inequality for Fourier transform and Schwartz function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have only recently started to study the Fourier transform in Schwartz space: and I've met a problem which I really do not have any idea on how to solve it.
The problem is precisely the following: consider $p\in[1,\infty]$ abd $k=2[1+\frac{d}{2}]$ where $d$ is the dimension of the ambient Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$, and a function $u\in L^p$. Then I want to find a constant $C>0$ such that $$|\langle\hat{u},\psi\rangle|\leq C\lVert \psi\rVert_{k,\mathcal{S}}\quad\psi\in\mathcal{S}$$
where $\mathcal{S}$ is the Schwartz space and $\hat{u}$ represents the Fourier transform of $u$.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\lVert \psi\rVert_{k,\mathcal{S}}$ and why do you fix $k$

Comment: @reuns, $\lVert \psi\rVert_{k,\mathcal{S}}=\max_{\alpha\in \mathcal{N}_0^{d},|\alpha|\leq k}\lVert (1+|\cdot|^2)^{\frac{k}{2}}\partial^{\alpha}\psi(x)\rVert_{L^{\infty}}$ which is a norm on $\mathcal{S}$

Comment: I think that by all reasonable definitions of the bracket, the LHS is simply $|\langle u,\,\hat{\psi}\rangle| \leq \|u\|_p\|\hat{\psi}\|_q$. Now, $\|\hat{\psi}\|_q \leq C\|(1+|x|^m)\hat{\psi}\|_{\infty}$, where $m$ is the smallest even integer greater than $d$. But $\|(1+|x|^m)\hat{\psi}\|_{\infty} \leq C\sup_{|\alpha| \leq m}\,\|\partial_{\alpha}\psi\|_{L^1}$. Similarly, $\|\partial_{\alpha}\psi\|_{L^1} \leq C\|(1+|x|^m)\partial_{\alpha}{\psi}\|_{\infty}$ and you’re basically done – as your $k$ seems to be my $m$.